# android sqlite query slow

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I have a database (sqlite) where I do this query :

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE+ " WHERE " +COLUM_NAME + "= ?" ;
```

then I set the Java Object accordinly, but I have a small problem. Its so slow. I have no idea why this one time query takes 1 - 2 sec.

Is there any feature of android where I am able to upgrade this speed ?

Comment: It is called indexing in SQL

Comment: It is not an android feature you are looking for, it is a database feature and it is called `index`. Try to add an index on field `column_name`

Comment: post more code so it could be understood why its slow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Indexing` made my queries **about 400x faster**.

Here you'll find a nice tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm.

Index all the fields involved in `WHERE` clauses as well as all those used for `joining` tables.